# Como obtener el precio de esta página por medio de Xpath para Google Sheets

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, scraping, xpath

estoy intentando crear una consulta para una investigación de mercado y necesito obtener precios desde [esta página](https://www.fishpond.co.nz/Music/Elephunk-2-LP-Black-Eyed-Peas/0602498608623)

He encontrado el precio en el código pero no logro generar una consulta xpath para Google Sheets. Soy un rookie en esto de los códigos y Web Scrapping, pero he logrado sacar la información de varios sitios web excepto de esta.

He intentado obtener la información del precio desde este código pero me es imposible lograr una consulta correcta

```
<div class="price-box__price-flexbox"><div class="price-box__pricebox-wrapper"><div class="price-box__grey">Our Price</div> <div class="price-box__our">$279</div></div> <!----></div>
```

Luego di con esta información dónde se encuentra contenido el "precio" pero no sé como extraer esa información en particular sin llevar toda la caja de información a la celda de Google Sheets

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Product","gtin13":"0602498608623","name":"Elephunk [2 LP]","description":"","brand":{"@type":"Brand","name":"VINYL"},"sku":119673628,"image":"https://cdn-r.fishpond.co.nz/0119/673/628/256485910/6.jpeg","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","gtin13":"0602498608623","sellURL":"0602498608623","identifier":"127277782","image":["https://cdn-r.fishpond.co.nz/0119/673/628/256485910/6.jpeg","https://cdn-r.fishpond.co.nz/0119/673/628/1566507205/6.jpeg","https://cdn-r.fishpond.co.nz/0119/673/628/1566507206/6.jpeg"],"priceSpecification":{"@type":"PriceSpecification","price":279,"priceCurrency":"NZD","priceTooHigh":false,"description":"Price includes delivery.","hasFeeForRD":true,"showBestPriceBadge":false,"perUnit":false},"availability":"InStock","name":"Elephunk [2 LP]","itemOffered":{"@type":"MusicAlbum","name":"Elephunk [2 LP]","author":[{"@type":"Person","name":"The Black Eyed Peas"}],"fileFormat":"Vinyl (2 Disc)","datePublished":"2016-09-30","identifier":[{"@type":"PropertyValue","name":"Country","value":"USA"},{"@type":"PropertyValue","name":"Studio/Live","value":"Studio"},{"@type":"PropertyValue","name":"Guest Artist","value":"Justin Timberlake; Papa Roach"},{"@type":"PropertyValue","name":"Label","value":"VINYL"},{"@type":"PropertyValue","name":"Dimensions","value":"31.6 x 0.9 x 32.3 centimetres (0.32 kg)"}],"description":{"@type":"PropertyValue","value":""}},"itemCondition":"NewCondition","deliveryLeadTime":{"@type":"QuantitativeValue","minValue":15,"maxValue":15,"unitCode":"DAY","alternateDescription":"Estimated delivery date: 10th Nov - 16th Nov from USA","description":"Ships from USA"},"isSmartSell":false,"isSmartSellBargain":false,"isGiftVoucher":false,"showXmasDeliveryMessage":0,"showXmasDeliveryEgiftMessage":0,"xmasDeliveryAvailable":0,"url":"https://www.fishpond.co.nz/Music/Elephunk-2-LP-Black-Eyed-Peas/0602498608623","price":279,"priceCurrency":"NZD","priceValidUntil":"2021-10-07","addOn":{"@type":"Offer","gtin13":"0825646120635","identifier":"346301712","name":"Private Dancer","image":"https://cdn-r.fishpond.co.nz/0065/794/706/189777312/6.jpeg","url":"https://www.fishpond.co.nz/Music/Private-Dancer-TINA-TURNER/0825646120635","priceSpecification":{"@type":"PriceSpecification","price":382,"priceCurrency":"NZD","priceTooHigh":false,"description":"Price includes delivery.","hasFeeForRD":true,"showBestPriceBadge":false,"perUnit":false}},"acceptedPaymentMethod":[{"@type":"LoanOrCredit","name":"AfterPay","logo":"https://cdn-w.fishpond.co.nz/fp_uploads/site_images/afterpay-logo-small.png","termsOfService":"https://www.fishpond.co.nz/helpdesk.php?question_id=1222","loanTerm":{"@type":"QuantitativeValue","value":4,"unitCode":"W4"},"amount":279,"currency":"NZD","loanRepaymentForm":{"@type":"RepaymentSpecification","loanPaymentAmount":{"@type":"MonetaryAmount","value":69.75,"currency":"NZD"},"numberOfLoanPayments":4,"loanPaymentFrequency":"fortnightly"}}]}],"detailedcategory":[{"@type":"currentCategory","name":"Music","url":"Music","position":1},{"@type":"currentCategory","name":"Vinyl","url":"Music/Vinyl","position":2},{"@type":"currentCategory","name":"Rap/Hip Hop","url":"Music/Vinyl/Rap_Hip_Hop","position":3},{"@type":"currentCategory","name":"Hip Hop","url":"Music/Vinyl/Rap_Hip_Hop/Hip_Hop","position":4}],"url":"https://www.fishpond.co.nz/Music/Elephunk-2-LP-Black-Eyed-Peas/0602498608623","category":"Music","mainItemBarcode":"0602498608623","additionalProperty":[{"@type":"PropertyValue","name":"newOrUsed","value":false}],"showSellYoursBox":false,"sellYoursCopyTextPrefix":""}
</script>
```

Me encuentro estancado con la formula en este momento hasta aquí

```
//script[@type='application/ld+json']
```

Alguna buen samaritano me puede guiar como obtener el precio del producto en esta web?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Espero estés muy bien!
Prueba esta:

```
=left(index(transpose(split(IMPORTxmL("https://www.fishpond.co.nz/Music/Elephunk-2-LP-Black-Eyed-Peas/0602498608623","//*[@*='application/ld+json']"),",""price"":",false)),2,1),find(",",index(transpose(split(IMPORTxmL("https://www.fishpond.co.nz/Music/Elephunk-2-LP-Black-Eyed-Peas/0602498608623","//*[@*='application/ld+json']"),",""price"":",false)),2,1))-1)
```